# Question about target data size to train a deep learning softmax classifier

Tags: numpy, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Dataset containing 777 readings (rows) and 29 features(columns), the last feature is labeled as 0 or 1. However, I am not sure how to separate the labels into samples.

I have separated my data into testing and training: 
From row 1 to 625, I reshaped my matrix to be 3D, 104 samples, containing 6 timesteps reading with 28 features. Array size (104,6,28)
Did the same from row 626 to 776 for the testing data resulting in an array of size (25,6,28).

Then, converted the last column(containing 0 or 1) to be 3D as well. The resulting size went to be:

test_y(25,6,1)
train_y(104,6,1)

after processing my data, I used the one hot encoding function on my Y data (labels) which I had removed before from the original 29 features data set.

The problem comes when I run my model to perform a softmax classification. It states that my second dense network expects to be 2D and I am passing a 3-dimensional array but my array must be 3D, otherwise the model would not know to what dataset the labels belong to.

Hope somebody could help me. Many thanks!

Reading a few papers out there, came to the conclusion that it might be the fact that some sliding windows models provide only 1 categorical label per window, meaning per (timesteps, features) only outputs 1 classification output?

My dataset contains readings from TCP/IP communications and each row is classified as either a cyberattack of type DDOS or no cyberattack of DDOS.
I don't have 1 window per case to classify the whole array as 1 or 0.

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from numpy import dstack
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

f=open('data/data_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[1:625]
train_x=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    train_x[i,:]=values

f=open('data/labels_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[1:625]
train_y=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    train_y[i,:]=values


f=open('data/data_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[626:776]
test_x=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    test_x[i,:]=values


f=open('data/labels_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[626:776]
test_y=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    test_y[i,:]=values

train_x=train_x.reshape(104,6,28)
train_y=train_y.reshape(104,6,1)
test_x=test_x.reshape(25,6,28)
test_y=test_y.reshape(25,6,1)

train_y=to_categorical(train_y)
test_y=to_categorical(test_y)


print(train_x.shape)
print(test_x.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_y.shape)


def evaluate_model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 32
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1],     train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[2]
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',
        input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',     metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
# evaluate model
    accuracy = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return accuracy
```

evaluate_model(train_x,train_y,test_x,test_y)

The expected output is just to have a softmax classifier that will predict if the tested data belongs to an attack or not.

Comment: Convert the labels to categorical variables using `keras.utils.to_categorical()` so that the train labels have a shape of ( 104 , 2 )

Comment: But doing so would mean I will be using only 1 label per window sample while I need 6 labels per window sample. This is where I am so confused, I don't have a window profile per class.